# Why wont a simple socket to the localhost connect?

Tags: c++, winapi, winsock, winsock2

I am following a tutorial that teaches me how to use win32 sockets(winsock2). I am attempting to create a simple socket that connects to the "localhost" but my program is failing when I attempt to connect to the local host(at the function connect()).

Do I need admin privileges to connect to the localhost? Maybe thats why it fails? Maybe theres a problem with my code? I have tried the ports 8888 & 8000 & they both fail.

Also if I change the port to 80 & connect to www.google.com I can connect BUT I get no response back. Is that because I haven't sent a HTTP request or am I meant to get some response back?

Here's my code (with the includes removed):

```
// Constants & Globals //
typedef unsigned long IPNumber;    // IP number typedef for IPv4
const int SOCK_VER    = 2;
const int SERVER_PORT = 8888;  // 8888
SOCKET mSocket        = INVALID_SOCKET;
SOCKADDR_IN sockAddr  = {0};
WSADATA wsaData;
HOSTENT* hostent;


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    // Initialise winsock version 2.2
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(SOCK_VER,2), &wsaData) != 0)
    {
        printf("Failed to initialise winsock\n");
        WSACleanup();
        system("PAUSE");
        return 0;
    }

    if (LOBYTE(wsaData.wVersion) != SOCK_VER || HIBYTE(wsaData.wVersion) != 2)
    {
        printf("Failed to load the correct winsock version\n");
        WSACleanup();
        system("PAUSE");
        return 0;
    }

    // Create socket
    mSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (mSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Failed to create TCP socket\n");
        WSACleanup();
        system("PAUSE");
        return 0;
    }


    // Get IP Address of website by the domain name, we do this by contacting(??) the Domain Name Server
    if ((hostent = gethostbyname("localhost")) == NULL)  // "localhost"  www.google.com
    {
        printf("Failed to resolve website name to an ip address\n");
        WSACleanup();
        system("PAUSE");
        return 0;
    }

    sockAddr.sin_port             = htons(SERVER_PORT);
    sockAddr.sin_family           = AF_INET;
    sockAddr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = (*reinterpret_cast <IPNumber*> (hostent->h_addr_list[0]));
    // sockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr=*((unsigned long*)hostent->h_addr);  // Can also do this

    // ERROR OCCURS ON NEXT LINE: Connect to server
    if (connect(mSocket, (SOCKADDR*)(&sockAddr), sizeof(sockAddr)) != 0)
    {
        printf("Failed to connect to server\n");
        WSACleanup();
        system("PAUSE");
        return 0;
    }

    printf("Got to here\r\n");
    // Display message from server
    char buffer[1000];
    memset(buffer,0,999);
    int inDataLength=recv(mSocket,buffer,1000,0);
    printf("Response: %s\r\n", buffer);

    // Shutdown our socket
    shutdown(mSocket, SD_SEND);

    // Close our socket entirely
    closesocket(mSocket);

    // Cleanup Winsock
    WSACleanup();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you have something listening on that port on your machine? (And yes, you need to send an HTTP request if you want a webserver to send you stuff.)

Comment: no, I dont have anything listening, I kindof thought that the local host would just respond lol

Comment: @JakeM please inform us when localhost "just responds", so we can name it Skynet and call the Terminator. Keep your computer away from the Big Red Button.

Comment: It will respond if you connect to a port that has a service listening, and the used protocol does not require you to talk first. For example, if I write in my linux machine: `telnet localhost 22` (that is the SSH port) it will reply `SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-7ubuntu1` without delay.

Comment: It did "just respond".  With a "port unreachable" ICMP packet, telling you that there is no socket listening on that port.  Which the sockets library converted to a failure return code from `connect`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone should be listening in the port you are connecting to. Try writing a small server program that will listen for incoming connections. If connect succeeds obviously you are connected to google but you need to send a HTTP request (from C? - that would be difficult).

Comment: Libcurl can help hide some nastinesses of writing HTTP requests in C.

Comment: Not so difficult: `const char *msg = "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n"; send(sock, msg, strlen(msg), 0);`. If you want to use HTTP 1.1 the minimum request would be `"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.google.com\r\n\r\n"`.

Answer (score 3):

As you're willing to use the TCP-Protocol wich is [connection based](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Connection_establishment) you will need a communication counterpart such as an application listening on port 8888 to respond to your connection initiation request (**SYN**-Packet in TCP Terms)

You could use the unix tool [netcat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat) (which is also availibla for other OS') to do so without the need of admin privileges...

```
nc -l 8888
```

... wich opens a listening socket on port 8888 on your local machine

However, on unix systems you aren't allowed to listen on so called [well known ports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers#Well-known_ports) without admin privileges.

For more information read about the [TCP Connection Life-Cycle](http://www.sdsusa.com/connections/)

Answer (score 0):

In order to connect to a TCP port on localhost, someone has to be listening on that port on your machine.

Apart from writing your own server there is a simple way to get some programs listening: Install the "Simple TCP/IP Services" feature on your machine. This will give you a "Quote of the day" server on port 17, a Daytime server on port 13, a Chargen server on port 19 and an echo server on port 7.

In order to install this, go to your "Programs and Features" or "Add/Remove Programs" or whatever it's called on your Windows, select "Turn Windows features on or off" and find and install the "Simple TCPIP Services" in the list.